# How to use sed/grep/cut to extract numericals between two brackets?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep, cut

I have a file with results as such:

```
   7499 (map g (range 1 1000)),(2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4)
   50 (map g (range 1 1000)),(2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 42)
   50 (map g (range 1 1000)),(2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 29)
   41 (map g (range 1 1000)),(2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 11)
   23 (map g (range 1 1000)),(2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4)
   3 (map g (range 1 1000)),(2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 5)
   100330 (map g (range 1 1000)),(2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 6)
```

I am very new to sed and has of yet not managed to get my desired output, which I would like to be:

```
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 42
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 29
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 11
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 5
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 6
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `awk -F'[()]' '{print $(NF-1)}' file.txt`

Comment: what is the logic in the distribution of your desired output? Once you know that, it is a matter of translating it into a regex

Comment: The sequence of numbers in the end are the actual results, which have been found from simulations. So that's what I want to extract.

Comment: What fedorqui meant was: here the logic is : print the contents of last bracket `()` on the line. After you know that, it's easy to write the regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this `grep`:

```
grep -oP '\(\K(\d+\s*)*(?=\))' file
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 42
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 29
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 11
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 5
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 6
```

**Explanation:**

- `\(` - Match literal `(`
- `\K` - Reset the match
- `(\d+\s*)*` Match 0 or more combination of digits followed by 0 or more space
- `(?=\))` - Lookahead to make sure it is followed by literal `)`
- `-P` - To use PCRE regex in grep
- `-o` - To output only matched string in input

Comment: How can I fix `\([\d\s?]+\)(?:.(?!\([\d\s]+\)))+$` to match last occurrence of `(numbers and spaces)`?

Comment: `grep -oP '.*\(\K[\d\s]+(?=\))' file`, and @MarounMaroun you mean without `\K` ? or this `grep -oP '(?<=\()[^()]*(?=\)[^)]*$)' file`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yes, I'm trying to use negative lookbehind to match last occurrence of this pattern: `(numbers or/and spaces)` (includes parenthesis).

Comment: @MarounMaroun: If you're trying to avoid `\K` for the same output then use: `grep -oP '(?<=\()(\d+\s*)*(?=\))' file`

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -oP '\(\K[0-9 ]+' file
```

Output:

```
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 42
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 29
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 11
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 5
2 2 4 4 4 4 4 4 6
```

Comment: Test this with: `echo '100330 (map g (10 range 1 1000)) (2 4 6)' | grep -oP '\(\K[0-9 ]+'`

Comment: This case is not specified.

Comment: Yes but title says: **extract numerals between two brackets?** (btw I didn't downvote, just having a discussion)